# Linux + Qt image

Tags: linux, arm, busybox

I am using Samsung ARM Cortex A9 Exynos4412 board.I boot "linux + Qt" img on the board. But there is no package manager on the board and no make , gcc commands.In /bin file there is file BusyBox I searched it they say swiss army knife of embedded linux but there is no opkg , apt-get , make, gcc or g++ commands on the board.How can I set these commands to my linux board.
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is two main ways:

1) If you are lucky, and your's board supplier provides set of pre-compiled packages, you can download sources of package managers (like opkg), cross-compile them on PC, copy to your board and then use pre-compiled packages.
2) If there is no such ability, then you can download sources of any utility you need (google can help to find), cross-compile on PC, copy to your board and then use.

Of cource, you need proper cross-compiler (for instance, CodeSourcery toolchain from Mentor Graphics).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I find that in BusyBox there is a "rpm" command kind of package manager.I get gcc files with "wget" command then rpm them but Actually problem is executable gcc doesnt compile.For example I tried to laod OpenSSH , "./configure" finds gcc but doesnt compile. If I can work with gcc I can easily install make command and openssl.

I try to cross-compile it thanks.